# Cual es la mejor forma de mandar a llamar una funcion de php con Js?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Quiero mandar a llamar un función que esta en un archivo php dentro de una clase, pero esto lo quiero mandar a llamar si se presiona un botón dentro de la pagina.

**Funcion que quiero mandar a llamar se encuentra en esta ruta:
C:\xampp\htdocs\Entec\application\controllers\Candidato.php\insertar;**

```html
<div class="col-md-5">
   <button style="margin-left:400px;" id="btnGuardar" type="button" 
    class="btn btn-info btn-min-width mb-1"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Guardar</button></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#btnGuardar").click(function() {
    
});
</script>
```

Comment: Puedes colocar tu código php de donde llamas? usas algún plugin? Jquery, Vue? Puedes darnos mas información?

Comment: creas un archivo que use la clase y llamas al archivo con ajax desde javascript (por ejemplo)

Comment: @JosueVargas Modifique la pregunta, para ver si se logra entender mejor

Comment: tienes que usar ajax en este caso

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#btnGuardar").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/endpoint.php",
        data: $("#form").serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log("error")
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo que edites la resupuesta con el boton [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/550192/edit) y exploques que has cambiado y porque, para que los que no entiendan puedan entender el porque de cada cosa y la proxima no tener el mismo problema.